# Не сохраняется файл на сервер

Tags: php, html, файлы

У меня есть папка Data. Она находиться вне сервера. Я загружаю туда картинку так:

```html
if (copy($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], '/../../Data/Users/'.$_COOKIE['id'].'/Posts/'.$_FILES['filename']['name'])) {
  echo 2;
    $file = '/../../Data/Users/'.$id.'/Posts/'.$ido.'/img.txt';
    $f = fopen($file, 'w');
    fwrite($f, $_FILES['filename']['name']);
    fclose($f);
 }
```

Получаю я файл отсюда:

```html
<form action=add_post.php method=post enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <table>
    <tr><td>Название поста:</td><td><input type=text name=name></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan=2>Текст:</td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan=2><textarea name=text rows=5 cols=40></textarea></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Картинка перед постом:</td><td><input name="filename" type="file" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type=submit value=Отправить ></td></form></tr>
   </table>
```

Ничего не загружается. Никакую ошибку не выдает. Помогите!

Answer (score 1):

> Она находиться вне сервера.

думаю это и есть ответ.

Comment: Нет, так как у меня есть другая форма и она загружает без проблем.